# Call ansible-playbook via webserver

Tags: python, apache, ansible

I am using a VM running ubuntu 16.04 and have installed ansible v2.4 and apache2 on it. I created a cgi script 'ansible_call.py' that uses the subprocess module, specifically

```
import os
import subprocess


print 'Content-type:text/html /r/n/r/n'

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    result = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/ansible-
playbook','/vagrant/playbooks/sample.yml'], stderr=devnull)

print result
```

Then I use curl to make a request to the webservice

```
curl localhost/cgi-bin/ansible-call.py
```

However I get the following error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at 
webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>  
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

I looked in the log and found the following

```
[Tue Nov 21 17:34:50.192002 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 3142:tid 140333400639232] [client 127.0.0.1:37534] AH01215: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/ansible-playbook', '/vagrant/playbooks/sample.yml']' returned non-zero exit status 2: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ansible-call.py
```

The python script itself runs okay. The exit status 2 is a mystery to me, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect [ansible "executable"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/bin/ansible#L108:L137) for possible status codes:

Some excerpts:

```
    except AnsibleOptionsError as e:
        ...
        exit_code = 5
    except AnsibleParserError as e:
        ...
        exit_code = 4
# TQM takes care of these, but leaving comment to reserve the exit codes
#    except AnsibleHostUnreachable as e:
#        ...
#        exit_code = 3
#    except AnsibleHostFailed as e:
#        ...
#        exit_code = 2
    except AnsibleError as e:
        ...
        exit_code = 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ...
        exit_code = 99
    except Exception as e:
        ...
        exit_code = 250
```

So exit code 2 suggest that you have failed hosts. You may want to catch process exception:

```
    try:
        res = check_output(cmd)
    except CalledProcessError as e:
        print 'Error occurred: (Code {}) {}'.format(e.returncode, e.output)
        res = None
```

Comment: Now I get an error of Permission Denied,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '~'
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
        "failed": true, 
        "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", 
        "stdout": ""
     }